# Add action button to Cordova InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, safari, action, inappbrowser

Has anyone been able to add an action button to the Cordova InAppBrowser plugin?  I am wanting to add an action button that allows users to open the link in the InAppBrowser in Safari.  I have searched around and have not been able to find an answer.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: the plugin don't allow to add more buttons, you should edit the plugin source code to add the button

Answer (score 0):

I had the same concern and had to find a solution for the requirements given to me. So I forked InAppBrowser and heavily modified it to make it vastly stylable. This is a bit of shameless self-promotion, but here it is.
https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser

Unfortunately, it only supports iOS and Android.

Comment: I am unable to install this plugin. I reported issue [here](https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser/issues/58)